# defining function for scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy

As I'm lazy I don't want to define function for optimizing this way:

```
f = lambda x, a, b, ...: a * x + c + ...
```

but I want to do such thing:

```
f = lambda x, p: p[0] * x + p[1] + ...
```

where p is array of initial parameters. The problem is - I don't know how to implement it. I tried

```
popt = optimize.curve_fit(f, x, y, p)
```

and even

```
popt = optimize.curve_fit(f, x, y, *p)
```

but such thing doesn't work - python interpreter yells about arguments' number mismatch. So is there any way to implement my idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it: you can use `*p` (see `f(xdata, *params)` in the docs):

```
>>> from scipy import optimize
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> x = np.arange(1, 4)
>>> y = x * 3 + 1
>>> 
>>> f = lambda x, *p: p[0] * x + p[1]
>>> popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(f, x, y, [1,-4])
>>> popt
array([ 3.,  1.])
>>> pcov
array([[  9.86076132e-32,  -1.97215226e-31],
       [ -1.97215226e-31,   4.60168861e-31]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, why when I ask questions I find solution myself? The solution is:

```
f = lambda x, *p: p[0] * x + p[1] + ...
popt = optimize.curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=p)
```

Comment: This problem-solving technique is called [talking to the bear](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2010-August/026357.html) :)